# gdb: how to view all memory associated with struct in hex

Tags: gdb

I have a pointer to a struct and I can print it in gdb using `print /x (*s)`.

However this gives me:

> ..., intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 3045, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 14735, intensity = 7 '\a'}, {dis
>   tance_2cm = 3345, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 14272, intensity = 7 '\a'}, {distance_2cm = 3735, intensity =
>    2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 14617, intensity = 6 '\006'}, {distance_2cm = 4239, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm =
>    9741, intensity = 5 '\005'}, {distance_2cm = 4892, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 10686, intensity = 4 '\004'
>   }, {distance_2cm = 6012, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 9906, intensity = 3 '\003'}}}, {head = {laser_block_id
>    = 61183, rotational_theta = 21191}, lasers_arary = {{distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0, inte
>   nsity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm =
>    0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distan
>   ce_2cm = 6426, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2040, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 6584, intensity = 2
>    '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 2154, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2282,
>    intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2428, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distan
>   ce_2cm = 26580, intensity = 33 '!'}, {distance_2cm = 2592, intensity = 5 '\005'}, {distance_2cm = 27180, intensity = 2
>   7 '\033'}, {distance_2cm = 2795, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 3045
>   , intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 14712, intensity = 22 '\026'}, {distance_2cm = 3342, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {
>   distance_2cm = 14181, intensity = 7 '\a'}, {distance_2cm = 3729, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 14474, intensi
>   ty = 6 '\006'}, {distance_2cm = 4228, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 9744, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2c
>   m = 4887, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 13075, intensity = 7 '\a'}, {distance_2cm = 5994, intensity = 3 '\003
>   '}, {distance_2cm = 9947, intensity = 4 '\004'}}}, {head = {laser_block_id = 61183, rotational_theta = 21207}, lasers_
>   arary = {{distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intens
>   ity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0
>   , intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance
>   _2cm = 2038, intensity = 6 '\006'}, {distance_2cm = 6548, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2146, intensity = 3 '
>   \003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2285, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, inte
>   nsity = 1 '\001'}, {distance_2cm = 2428, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 26498, intensity = 33 '!'}, {distance_
>   2cm = 2590, intensity = 5 '\005'}, {distance_2cm = 26177, intensity = 29 '\035'}, {distance_2cm = 2792, intensity = 3
>   '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 0, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 3044, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 14743,
>    intensity = 7 '\a'}, {distance_2cm = 3344, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 14147, intensity = 7 '\a'}, {distan
>   ce_2cm = 3728, intensity = 2 '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 14520, intensity = 13 '\r'}, {distance_2cm = 4222, intensity = 2
>    '\002'}, {distance_2cm = 14567, intensity = 5 '\005'}, {distance_2cm = 4885, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 1
>   0842, intensity = 6 '\006'}, {distance_2cm = 5978, intensity = 3 '\003'}, {distance_2cm = 9964, intensity = 6 '\006'}}
>   }}}, sd = {gps_time_stamp = 59467414, status_type = 55 '7', status_value = 33 '!'}}

I want to view it in hex, something like the hypothetical output below:

```
00000000: 2369 6e63 6c75 6465 203c 6368 6563 6b2e
00000010: 683e 0a0a 2369 6e63 6c75 6465 2022 635f
00000020: 7665 6c6f 6479 6e65 2f61 7267 7061 7273
00000030: 652e 6822 0a23 696e 636c 7564 6520 2263
```

Is there a way to do this with gdb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with the `x` command.  The simplest way is to first find the size of your structure, and then pass this as an argument to `x`.  Something like:

```
(gdb) print sizeof(whatever)
$1 = 1024
(gdb) x/512xh &whatever
```

Decoding `x/512xh`:

- 512 is the repeat count, here half the size of the structure, because your example showed 2 bytes per word;
- `x` means print in hex;
- `h` means "halfword", aka 2 bytes.

The gdb manual explains all the flags that can be used here.

You can do this in a fancier way using `eval` to compute the length for you.  If you're doing this a lot I would suggest perhaps writing a new command in Python that does a bit of processing and then invokes `x`.

Comment: Was just about to comment on my post. x /22xb sld did what I needed. I just misunderstood the manual.